# Calculate occurrences per group of events - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

having the following rdd

```
BBBBBBAAAAAAABAABBBBBBBB
AAAAABBAAAABBBAAABAAAAAB
```

I need to calculate the numbers of iterations per group of event, so, for this example the expected output should be:

```
BBBBBBAAAAAAABAABBBBBBBB    A -> 2   B -> 3
AAAAABBAAAABBBAAABBCCCCC    A -> 3   B -> 4  C-> 1

Final Output ->  A -> 5   B -> 7  C-> 1
```

I have implemented the splitting and them a sliding for each character to try to obtain the values, but I cannot obtain the expected result.

Thanks,

Comment: Please check here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Man, you keep posting this problem over and over again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val baseRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("BBBBBBAAAAAAABAABBBBBBBB", "AAAAABBAAAABBBAAABBCCCC"))
baseRDD.flatMap(x => "(\\w)\\1*".r.findAllMatchIn(x).map(x => (x.matched.charAt(0), 1)).toList).reduceByKey((accum, current) => accum + current).foreach(println(_))
```

**Result**

(C,1)
(B,6)
(A,5)

Hope this is what you wanted.